# Creating a localy stored "shopping cart"

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a locally stored shopping cart and can't figure out why the plus/minus buttons I have set up won't work.

I have included pictures of my code the first is the shopping cart, the second being my javascript to increase/decrease by 1 each button click.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQPK5.jpg

any help would be appreciated

```
<script>


var value1 = localStorage.getItem('name1') || 0;

var value2 = localStorage.getItem('name2') || 0;

var value3 = localStorage.getItem('name3') || 0;

// get values from the input in shopping class file



$(‘.quantity’).on(‘click’, ‘.btn’, function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
$input = $this.closest(‘div’).find(‘input’),
value = parseInt($input.val()),
btn = $this.data(‘btn’);

if (btn === ‘minus’) {
value = value > 1 ? value – 1 : 0;
} else {
value = value < 100 ? value + 1 : 100;
 }

$input.val(value);
 });

 $(‘.delete-btn’).on(‘click’, function(e) {
 $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});

</script>


<div class="shoppingCart">
  <!-- Title -->
  <h1>
   <b> Shopping Cart</b>
  </h1>

  <!-- Product #1 -->
   <div class="item">
    <div class="buttons">
      <span class="delete-btn"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="image">
      <img src="Halo 3.png" style = "width:75px"alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <span>Halo 3</span>


    </div>

    <div class="quantity">
      <button class="btn" type="button"  name="button">
        <img src="plus.png" style = "width:10px" alt="" />
      </button>
      <input type="text" name="name1" value="1">
      <button class="btn" type="button" name="button">
          <img src="minus.png" style = "width:10px" alt="" />
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="total-price">$69.99</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just edited and posted the code sorry

Comment: I also need to have the cart consistent across multiple pages is the way I'm doing allow for that functionality

Answer (score 0):

I found a few errors which I've corrected and placed in this fiddle for you to work with. One syntactical error was the use of these chars `‘’–` which were replaced to `'-`.

Also in your click() function `$this.data('btn')` was returning `undefined`. In the jsfiddle I reworked this so that you get the reference to the button, and I also moved the variable referencing the input outside of the click() function because you really only need to find it once, and not each time to click.

https://jsfiddle.net/4mhLz6dx/

```
<div class="shoppingCart">
  <!-- Title -->
  <h1>
   <b> Shopping Cart</b>
  </h1>

  <!-- Product #1 -->
   <div class="item">
    <div class="buttons">
      <span class="delete-btn"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="image">
      <img src="Halo 3.png" style = "width:75px"alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="description">
      <span>Halo 3</span>


    </div>

    <div class="quantity">
      <button class="btn" type="button"  name="plus">
        <img src="plus.png" style = "width:10px" alt="" />
      </button>
      <input type="text" name="name1" value="1">
      <button class="btn" type="button" name="minus">
          <img src="minus.png" style = "width:10px" alt="" />
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="total-price">$69.99</div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var value1 = localStorage.getItem('name1') || 0;

var value2 = localStorage.getItem('name2') || 0;

var value3 = localStorage.getItem('name3') || 0;

// get values from the input in shopping class file

var inputTotal = $('.quantity input');

$('.quantity').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var btn = $(this),
  //$input = $this.closest('div').find('input'), // store the reference to this since it doesn't change so you don't look it up each call
  value = parseInt(inputTotal.val());


  if (btn.attr('name') === 'minus') {
    value = value > 1 ? value - 1 : 0;
  } 
  else {
    value = value < 100 ? value + 1 : 100;
  }

    inputTotal.val(value);
});

$('.delete-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, it works in JSFiddle but when I'm moving it over to my code it still isn't working I'm not too sure why also I had the lookup for each button on each call because I have 3 items in the cart, my thought was that I would need to find which one I am increasing, or am i mistaken?

Comment: In that case then yes you would prob want to find the input within the click function. If it isn't working, make sure you copied the html as well, I changed the names of the buttons you had there so they would work with the jquery selector.

Comment: Another idea for why it may not be working is because the script might need to come after the html, or you could do it the jquery way and wrap everything in the function within a [`$( document ).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: so i copied the JSFiddle code into a separate HTML document to test if it would work by itself and still does not work, you said to wrap it in a document.ready() but I'm not sure how to do that also the javascript comes after the HTML so its not that, do you have any other suggestions?